# Basic design of a data access layer using the DataMapper pattern

Tags: design-patterns, orm

I'm trying to understand the [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern by implementing it myself for one of my domain objects.

So far, I have:

```
class MyDomainObject
  <attributes>
  <business logic methods>

class MyDomainObjectMapper
  save
  update
  delete
  get
```

Now, I need get many `MyDomainObject`s.  These could possibly be held cached in memory (saving many calls to the database).  There could also be filter conditions.

Where does this functionality go, according to the pattern?  I'm not sure if I should add methods to `MyDomainObjectMapper` or create a new class.

Answer (score 2):

That's what an [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) is for.

> *Ensures that each object gets loaded only once by keeping every loaded object in a map. Looks up objects using the map when referring to them.*
>
> For a full description see [P of EAA](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) page **195**
>
> [image: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/idMapperSketch.gif]
>
> ...An Identity Map keeps a record of all objects that have been read from the database in a single business transaction. Whenever you want an object, you check the Identity Map first to see if you already have it.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of that before.  Can you explain more about which class is responsible for managing the map?  (or maybe it's its own class?)

Comment: Look at http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html Your mapper would use the identity map.

Comment: The Map is a class of its own.